# Listing installed packages with yum and rpm mismatch

Tags: centos

How can I efficiently list installed and available packages on Cent OS?

I have already tried `yum list` installed, which is supposed to output the list of all installed while `rpm -qa` produces a different result in size.

Which one should I trust? Or am I omitting something?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is: `rpm -qa` is better to know what **is** installed (RPM packages, right! ). Whereas `yum`  is better to know what **could be** installed and find required dependencies. It is usually fine to use `yum` for both purposes.

I tested on a CentOS 7 system. They have almost identical list, except that rpm also reports some `gpg-pubkey` pseudo packages (try `rpm -qa gpg-pubkey\*`).

If you want to compare the lists on your system, first get the `rpm`'s list:

```
$ rpm -q -a --qf '%{NAME}\t%{ARCH}\t%{VERSION}\t%{RELEASE}\n' | sort > /tmp/rpm-qa.lst
```

Then extract YUM's list (using `repoquery` which is part of package `yum-utils`:

```
$ repoquery -q -a --installed  --qf '%{NAME}\t%{ARCH}\t%{VERSION}\t%{RELEASE}' | sort > /tmp/repo-qa.lst
```

Then compare:

```
$ diff -u0 /tmp/rpm-qa.lst /tmp/repo-qa.lst
--- /tmp/rpm-qa.lst     2015-03-08 16:07:38.297325253 +0100
+++ /tmp/repo-qa.lst    2015-03-08 16:07:43.281438369 +0100
@@ -143,1 +142,0 @@
-gpg-pubkey     (none)  352c64e5        52ae6884
```

(See also question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190203/16640)

Answer (score 0):

Both commands works in the same way only difference is 'yum list installed' output maybe bigger than 'rpm -qa' because yum will show package dependencies also in its output.

While installing a package using rpm, we need to manually install the dependencies whereas yum will do that automatically. So in this case if you want to list the packages only use, 'rpm -qa' or if you need to list all the packages and dependencies associated with it use 'yum list installed'